# Kotlin version conflict?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on maintaining an Android library that is using Kotlin v1.2.1.
There are more than 500 applications using the library (published on Maven).
What happens if I upgrade Kotlin version to the latest - current is 1.6.10?

- Any conflicts?
- Do 500 using applications need to upgrade also?

Answer (score 0):

Any conflicts?
-> probably;

Do 500 using applications need to upgrade also?
-> only those that present conflicts, because probably the version will only be affecting if something that causes this conflict is contained in the latest version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).